# How do I compare properties from reflection to a type?

Tags: c#, reflection

Basically, what I want to do is loop over the list of properties on a class, and where they are a particular type I will check a property of that owned property, then set another property to true.

I wrote the code below to illustrate what I want to do, however it will not compile because it says cannot convert type System.Reflection.PropertyInfo to type ThermodynamicState. In addition it gives the warning that the given expression is never of ThermodynamicState type.

How do I convert each property in the list of properties reflection gives into an object of that type?

```
    public void BasisChanged()
    {
        foreach (ThermodynamicProperty thermoProperty in this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType is ThermodynamicProperty && !((ThermodynamicProperty)p.PropertyType).IsBasis))
        {
            thermoProperty.BasisChanged = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show *this* class definition. Error is obvious because you are checking for props of type X and lopping with variable of type Y.

Comment: @nikhilvartak I just saw that it should be the list of ThermodynamicProperties. this refers to a class of type ThermodynamicState. But the underlying problem is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you are trying something like the following:

```
public void BasisChanged()
{
    foreach (var p in GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => typeof(ThermodynamicProperty).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType)))
    {
        var value = (ThermodynamicProperty)p.GetValue(this);
        if (!value.IsBasis)
            value.BasisChanged = true;
    }
}
```

You have to check the property's type via `PropertyType`. `IsAssignableFrom()` checks if objects of this type can be assigned to a `ThermodynamicProperty` variable. Then you get the current object with `GetValue()` and set the `BasisChanged` property.

Note that this assumes `ThermodynamicProperty` to be a reference type. If it is a value type, you have to set it back after changing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (PropertyInfo p in this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(ThermodynamicProperty)))
{
    ThermodynamicProperty propertyObject = (ThermodynamicProperty)p.GetValue(this);
    if (!propertyObject.IsBasis)
    {
        propertyObject.BasisChanged = true;
     }
}
```